# get the storename form within an embedded app with shopify api?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I need to access the storename of a store from an embedded app after the initial authentication. An example of a situation is say that you had some form of dashboard...You may need to make a call to some DB to get data for it...you may need to use the token here as well and it is associated with a store...so my question is how do you go about getting that token after they have already been authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

99/100 you store the shop name in the authenticated session for your convenient use in as many ways as you can see fit.